# Deployment of basic Java web application to AWS : javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, deployment, web-applications

I keep getting this error while trying to deploy an application to AWS:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment:
SampleWebApplication".
javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

Here is what I do:

1. I create new Maven project based on maven-archetype-webapp 1.0
2. I configure the pom.xml file with dependencies (full file below)
3. I type in whatever to index.jsp (it's supposed to be super easy application)
4. I run it on tomcat7:run, it works like a charm on http://localhost:8080/
5. I create AWS Server
6. I select the project, I choose Amazon Web Services Tool --> Deploy to AWS Elastik Beanstalk, choose the added server and I keep getting this message:

[image]

I am not able to find any information about this error in the internet. The only thing that I have found is that it is connected to Java version, but I am running Java 1.8 (as was suggested in one post that I found).

Can anyone please help me? I am following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/eclipse-deployment-part-2-deploying-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) instruction for deployment of the application.
I'm super new to AWS so I don't even know where to start!

index.jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello There!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dominikazb</groupId>
<artifactId>SampleWebApplication</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SampleWebApplication Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.50</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>SampleWebApplication</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <wtpContextName>todo</wtpContextName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}
                </webappDirectory>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Project structure

[image: Project structure]

Please, please, please help!

Comment: I have the same question:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198740/updating-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception) And the same number of answers...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find an answer to this problem in the website:
https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-eclipse/issues/123
The examples there were in Unix. Mine is in Window 7. What I did base on the website suggestion is:

Find where is the file jaxb-api-2.2.5.jar located. I am not sure if version 2.2.5 is a must. Suggest try whatever you have.
Mine is located in
`C:\Users\myUserName\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.5.`

Exit the Eclipse IDE.

Open PowerShell in Admin mode.
`cd` to your user directory (my case `C:\Users\myUserName`) and execute the following command to open the Eclipse IDE with a -dev option which points to the jaxb-api-2.2.5.jar.
`C:\Users\myUserName\eclipse\jee-2020-09\eclipse\eclipse -dev $(ls ~/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/*/*[0-9].jar | Select-Object -Last 1)`

Certainly, the location of your eclipse.exe can be different.

Happy coding!

Comment: There is a typo. C:\Users\myUserName.m2\repository  should be C:\Users\myUserName\.m2\repository

Comment: There is also a paste error: ~/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api//[0-9].jar should be ~/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/*/*[0-9].jar