# Updating AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, jaxb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

A created a simple Dynamic Web project in Eclipse.
I try to Run on Server choosing the
AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
I get this error message:

An internal error occurred during: "**Updating AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment: test-env".
javax/xml/bind/JAXBException**

How to solve this problem?
Thanks!